# React state not changing, when using setState

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to make a switch become enabled/disabled whenever the user interacts with it. This is done by using a `onChange` event, which then changes a context stats `key, value`

However, when console logging the output. The state does not seem to be changing.

Context is an object of the values below, by default all values are null.
context after update:

```
newSettings:
    anti_scam:
        enabled: null
        log_channel: null
        punishment_type: null
```

tmpSettings obj

```js
newSettings:
    anti_scam:
        enabled: true
        log_channel: null
        punishment_type: null
```

As you can see, the value of `enabled` is changed. But the react context state is not. This means the switch is always either disabled, or enabled depending on the users settings, and they cannot change it.

**What I have tried**
Originally I was using a mutable obj. But then I found out that sometimes this does not cause react to re-render the page. So, I switched to making an immutable copy, and modifying the values I wish to change from that. But this still has not fixed the problems.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```js
const EnableSwitch = () => {
  const { context, setSaveEnabled } = useContext(SaveContext);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const tmpSettings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context));
    tmpSettings.newSettings.anti_scam.enabled = event.target.checked;
    
    setSaveEnabled(tmpSettings);
  };

  return (
    <Fade bottom>
      <div>
        <Switch
          checked={context.newSettings.anti_scam.enabled}
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
        />
      </div>
    </Fade>
  );
};
```

`<SaveContext.Provider value={{ context, setSaveEnabled }}>`

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const SaveContext = createContext({
    context: {
        saveEnabled: false,
        oldSettings: {
            anti_scam: {
                enabled: null,
                log_channel: null,
                punishment_type: null,
            }
        },
        newSettings: {
            anti_scam: {
                enabled: null,
                log_channel: null,
                punishment_type: null,
            }
        }
    },
    setSaveEnabled: () => { }
});

export const SaveProvider = SaveContext.Provider;
export default SaveContext;
```

Comment: We will also need to see the context provider

Comment: Apologies, I have added it.

Comment: `setSaveEnabled: () => { }` - it's an empty function... What exactly are you expecting it to do?

Comment: There is no state in this code. You've named things like they should be state, but that does not make them state. Look into [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: @jaalkamza i mean we'll need to see the code where you render a `<SaveProvider value={someValue} />`, and the related code that determines `someValue`. If you're not rendering one of those, then you only get the default value.

Comment: `<SaveContext.Provider value={{ context, setSaveEnabled }}>`

Comment: @jaalkamza add to the question please, and include what those values are. This is most likely where your problem is.

Comment: The values are already in the question, it is the `saveContext` code. (Last code block)

Comment: That last code block shows us the default values of the context. If that's all you have, then that's the problem: you need an actual implementation, not just a default value. But i think you do have more...  you've shown us the code `<SaveContext.Provider value={{ context, setSaveEnabled }}>`. What is the variable `context`? what is the variable `setSaveEnabled`? Those are the important parts.

Comment: Sorry that I've not explained properly. `context` in this case is the default values as shown in the last code block. 

For now, a key inside of `context` is edited when a user interacts with my switch component

`tmpSettings.newSettings.anti_scam.enabled = event.target.checked;`

This is in the 3rd codeblock in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is a way to get values from component A to component B, but it will not implement anything else for you. If you want to pass state from component A to component B, then component A will need to implement that state, using `useState` and other such code. Since you're just using the default value, none of that is happening.

So you will need to make a component near the top of the tree that is something like this:

```
const Example = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    saveEnabled: false,
    oldSettings: {
      anti_scam: {
        enabled: null,
        log_channel: null,
        punishment_type: null,
      },
    },
    newSettings: {
      anti_scam: {
        enabled: null,
        log_channel: null,
        punishment_type: null,
      },
    },
  });

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      context: state,
      setSaveEnabled: /* some function which updates the state */,
    }
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <SaveContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </SaveContext.Provider>
  )
};
```